# Parsing a string in MSAccess VBA with varying numbers of delimiters

Tags: vba, string, ms-access, parsing, delimiter

In MSAccess VBA, I'm trying to parse a name field into last, first, middle.  The problem is that the incoming format is not consistent:

```
Jones         John  Q
Doe   Jane
Smith Robert     X
```

This is what I'm doing

```
Dim rsNames As DAO.Recordset
Set rsNames = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblInput")
If Not (rsNames.EOF And rsNames.BOF) Then
    rsNames.MoveFirst 
    Do Until rsNames.EOF = True
        strFullName = rsNames!Name
        intLength = Len(strFullName)
        intSpacePos = InStr(strFullName, " ")
        strLname = Left(strFullName, intSpacePos - 1)
        strFname = Mid(strFullName, intSpacePos, intLength - (intSpacePos - 1))
        strFname = Trim(strFname)
        If Len(strFname) + Len(strLname) + (intSpacePos - 1) < intLength Then
                  strMI = Right(strFullName, 1)
        End If
        rsNames.Edit
        rsNames!LastName = strLname
        rsNames!FirstName = strFname
        rsNames!MiddleInitial = strMI
        rsNames.Update
        rsNames.MoveNext
    Loop
```

Results

```
LastName: Jones
FirstName: John     Q
Middle Initial: Q

LastName: Doe
FirstName: Jane
Middle Initial: E
```

If I change this line
`strFname = Mid(strFullName, intSpacePos, intLength - (intSpacePos - 1))` to
`strFname = Mid(strFullName, intSpacePos, intLength - (intSpacePos)`, the lines with middle initials parse correctly, but the lines without middle initials cut off the last character of the first name and move it to the middle initial field `(Doe   Jan   E)`

I've tried using split and replace but neither works properly because of the varying numbers of spaces separating the fields.  I'm wondering if my only option is to read the string character by character and building the individual fields that way, but before I go down that path, am I missing something obvious?  I have no control over the incoming file.

Comment: you can reduce all runs of multiple spaces to single spaces using something like `Do While Instr(strFullName, "  ")>0: strFullName = Replace(strFullName, "  ", " "):Loop` and then split on space.  If the UBound of the resulting array is 1 (lower bound will be 0) then there's no middle initial.

Answer (score 0):

I'll propose you to use split() function, in this manner:

```
Dim rsNames As DAO.Recordset
Dim strLname As String, strFname As String, strMI As String
Dim i As Integer

Dim x, arr As Variant

Set rsNames = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblInput")

If Not (rsNames.EOF And rsNames.BOF) Then
    'rsNames.MoveFirst
    Do Until rsNames.EOF = True
        arr = Split(rsNames!Name)
        strLname = ""
        strFname = ""
        strMI = ""
        i = 0
        For Each x In arr
          If (x <> "") Then
            If (i = 0) Then
              strLname = x
            ElseIf (i = 1) Then
              strFname = x
            Else
              strMI = x
            End If
            i = i + 1
          End If
          '
          If (i > 2) Then
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
        '
        rsNames.Edit
        rsNames!LastName = strLname
        rsNames!FirstName = strFname
        rsNames!MiddleInitial = strMI
        rsNames.Update
        rsNames.MoveNext
    Loop
    
End If

rsNames.Close
Set rsNames = Nothing
```

We use a loop to find non empty split strings as LastName, FirstName and Middle initial.

This pure VBA code avoids us to use extra `VBScript.RegExp` replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I would lean towards using RegEx and Split:

```
Private Sub Test()
   Dim strFullName As String
   Dim NameParts As Variant
   
   strFullName = "Jones         John  Q"

   With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
      .Pattern = "\s+"
      .Global = True
      strFullName = .Replace(strFullName, " ")
   End With
   
   NameParts = Split(strFullName, " ")
End Sub
```

NameParts is an array containing Last, First, and possibly Middle names.

Answer (score 0):

Are First Name and Last Name always in the same position?  If so, the use of split can be use to determine the existence of the middle, i may be missing something though, i'd go for

```
Dim a() As String
a() = Split(s, Chr(32))

strLastName = a(0)
strFirstName = a(1)
If UBound(a) = 2 Then
    strMiddle = a(2)
Else
    strMiddle = ""
End If
    
Debug.Print strFirstName, strMiddle, strLastName
```

or something a bit less elegant

```
If Len(s) - Len(Replace(s, Chr(32), "")) = 2 Then
    strMiddle = Right(s, Len(s) - InStrRev(s, Chr(32)))
End If
```